# Redirect Log4j to specific file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

In a batch application that read and parse multiple files, the specifications ask me to output logs for each file separately.

How can I do this?

Example:

```
for(File f : allFiles) {
     //TODO after this line all log should be output to "<f.getName()>.log"

     LOGGER.debug('Start processing '+f.getName());

     // process the file by calling librairies (JPA, spring, whatever ...)

     LOGGER.debug('End processing '+f.getName());
}
```

So that, if I have 3 files to process, in the end, I want to have 3 log files.

What I have done so far is the following class.

```
import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;

public final class LoggerHelper {

    /**
     * Functional logger
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("BATCH_LOGGER");

    /**
     * Pattern for the layout of the logger
     */
    private static final String PATTERN_LAYOUT = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd [HH:mm:ss]} %m%n";

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    private LoggerHelper() {
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the loggers
     * 
     * @param filename
     *            the name of the file where the logs will be written
     * @throws IOException
     *             if a problem occur when instantiate a file appender
     */
    public static void initLoggers(String filename) throws IOException {
        // change functional appender
        LOGGER.removeAllAppenders();
        LOGGER.addAppender(new FileAppender(new PatternLayout(PATTERN_LAYOUT), filename));
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    }

    /**
     * Get the batch logger
     * 
     * @return the batch Logger
     */
    public static Logger getLogger() {
        return LOGGER;
    }
}
```

But I have to replace all LOGGER calls with `LoggerHelper.getLogger().debug(...)`.
And with this solution, I can't log frameworks logs.

```
for(File f : allFiles) {
     //TODO after this line all log should be output to "<f.getName()>.log"
     LoggerHelper.initLoggers(f.getName());

     LoggerHelper.getLogger().debug('Start processing '+f.getName());

     // process the file by calling librairies (JPA, spring, whatever ...)

     LoggerHelper.getLogger().debug('End processing '+f.getName());
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the solution I finally implemented.
I share it here, if this can help others...

First, the helper class that reload the log4j configuration.
Note that it (re)set some System properties. Those properties will be used in the log4j file directly.

```
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

public final class LogHelper {

    private final static String LOG4J_XML_FILENAME = "log4j.xml";
    private final static String LOG_APPLI_DIRECTORY = "LOG_APPLI_DIRECTORY";
    private final static String FILENAME = "FILENAME";

    public static void initLogsForCurrentFile(String currentFile, String logDir) {
        Assert.hasLength(currentFile);
        Assert.doesNotContain(currentFile, File.pathSeparator);

        ClassPathResource log4jxml = new ClassPathResource(LOG4J_XML_FILENAME);
        if (!log4jxml.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The [log4j.xml] configuration file has not been found on the classpath.");
        }

        // TODO Define variables that could be used inside the log4j
        // configuration file
        System.setProperty(FILENAME, FileUtils.removeExtension(currentFile));
        System.setProperty(LOG_APPLI_DIRECTORY, logDir);

        // Reload the log4j configuration
        try {
            DOMConfigurator.configure(log4jxml.getURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "A problem occured while loading the log4j configuration.",
                    e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding log4j file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- This log4j file will be reloaded multiple times -->
    <!-- so that each files processed by the applicatin will have their own log file -->
    <!-- ${LOG_APPLI_DIRECTORY} = the log directory -->
    <!-- ${FILENAME} = the basename of the current file processed by the batch -->

    <appender name="batch-appender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file"
            value="${LOG_APPLI_DIRECTORY}/batch-${FILENAME}.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p  %-40.40c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- ================ -->
    <!-- Root logger -->
    <!-- ================ -->
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="batch-appender" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

With such solution, we stay as close as possible to what we usually do to configure log4j.
And moreover this solution keeps the configuration in the log4j file with no configuration in the java source code.

Answer (score 1):

You are already on a good track. I guess your misstake is to create new loggers. The solution might be to add different appenders to the same logger. So your logger helper just have to replace the appender (as you already did at your code):

```
private static final class LoggerHelper {

    private static final String PATTERN_LAYOUT = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd [HH:mm:ss]} %m%n";

    private static final Layout LAYOUT = new PatternLayout(PATTERN_LAYOUT);

    public static final void setFileOutputOfLogger(Logger log, String fileName) throws IOException {
        log.removeAllAppenders();
        log.addAppender(new FileAppender(LAYOUT, fileName));
    }
}
```

That is something you can call once within your loop.

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FileStuff.class);

for(File f : allFiles) {
     LoggerHelper.setFileOutputOfLogger(log, f.getName());
```

All the framework output will not be touched.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I posted the final solution I used with no configuration in the java source code.